# Couchbase N1QL query to find document that has a field value containing the ID of another document that exists

Tags: nosql, couchbase, sql++

I have a Couchbase bucket "businesses" of documents, e.g.: business listings, like listing_HomeDepot, listing_Lowes, listing_DansHardware.

Each listing_* doc has a field businessInfo that contains part of the key to another document in the same bucket. E.g., listing_DansHardware has "businessInfo": "3a4tg", and there should be a document with key info_3a4tg. The document info_3a4tg has an "id" field with "3a4tg" in it.

Let's say Dans Hardware closed down and the info_3a4tg document got deleted. I want to select all businesses that are in the bucket, but filter out any businesses with orphaned business info references.

I tried:
select * from businesses b1 where b1.category='hardware' and exists (select * from businesses b2 use keys 'info_'||b1.businessInfo)

but that didn't work. I got some "Document key must be string" error.  Any tips, please?

Comment: These answers helped! So the strange thing is that even though the N1QL result's allRows contains all the documents I wanted, the warnings/errors contains a lot of the same "Document key must be string: <nil>" warnings/errors. I see this when I debug the N1QL result. So even though I get the docs i need, I'm concerned that a lot of inefficient things are happening in the background. I'll share the debug output in the next comment. There are 5679 of them, but I truncated them in the comment for brevity.

Comment: N1qlQueryResult{ status='success', finalSuccess=true, parseSuccess=true, allRows=[ { ..<truncated>.. }, .., <truncated>, .., { ..<truncated>.. } ], signature={ "": "" }, info=N1qlMetrics{ resultCount=100, errorCount=0, warningCount=5679, ... }, profileInfo={ }, errors=[ { "msg": "Document key must be string: <nil>", "code": 0 }, ..., { "msg": "Document key must be string: <nil>", "code": 0 } ], ... }

Answer (score 1):

|| operation can be done on string only. Check if you have businessInfo has string on all the documents. OR use IS_STR(b1.businessInfo) predicate

```
SELECT b1.*
FROM businesses AS b1
WHERE b1.category = 'hardware'
      AND IS_STR(b1.businessInfo)
      AND EXISTS (SELECT RAW 1 
                  FROM businesses b2 USE KEYS "info_" || b1.businessInfo);
```

OR

```
SELECT b1.*
FROM businesses AS b1
JOIN businesses AS b2 ON KEYS "info_" || b1.businessInfo
WHERE b1.category = 'hardware';
```

Comment: if businessInfo isn't there, that also causes this error. Another predicate that might help is `businessInfo IS NOT MISSING'